# Why no GCC warning for re-definition of struct in C?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, warnings, definition

```
main.h
struct tagname {
     int m1;
     int m2;
};

main.c
#include "main.h"

int main(void) {
    
    struct tagname d1;
    d1.m1 = 7;

    struct tagname {
        float s1;
        float s2;
        float s3;
    };

    struct tagname e1;
    e1.s1 = 0;
}
```

I am using XC16 v1.60 (which I believe uses GCC v4.5.1 as the base) with -Wall, -Wextra, -Wshadow, and a host of other flags which I don't think are relevant, and I would have thought (hoped?) that the compiler would issue a warning here.  What am I missing?
Edit: Apologies, I have updated the question with the extra detail desired.

Comment: Given an expression statment like `d1.m1 = 7;` may not appear at file scope, this code is far from complete enough to discuss meaningfully. Please post a [mre].

Comment: Not only am I getting errors for not putting the semicolon after structs with GCC, but I am in fact getting an error for redefining the struct as opposed to even a warning. Assuming this is a code snippet with a global scope, you should be getting errors for assigning values to `d1.m1` and `e1.s1` outside a function too. There may be something wrong with your GCC. Have you tried clang?

Comment: For what it’s worth, GCC 4.5.1 is **ancient**. Install a newer version.

Comment: I guess you must be either defining the structs differently in different compilation units, or defining them differently in different scopes.

Comment: If the first structure definition is at file scope and the second is at function scope, then there is no problem.  If the second is in a compound statement within a function, there is also no problem.  The two definitions must be in different scopes; they can't be in the same scope.

Comment: Apologies all.  I've added the detail which I hope will clarify.

Comment: W.r.t. GCC version: this is the latest version I see referenced in the XC16 documentation.  I guess I cannot swear if they have updated beyond that but it doesn't appear transparent.  XC16 is version 1.60

Comment: -Wshadow is only implemented in the C++ front-end if I understand the doc.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I do not get that from [the documentation for the current version](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options). Parts of it apply only to C++, such as shadowing class members, and it actually indicates partly opposite, that warning on shadowing structure tags does not work in C++, suggesting it does in C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I saw this as well which is why I thought I was missing something more basic, as it seemed fairly clear from the description.  Granted the 4.5.1 documentation is less clear / detailed, and I am having trouble finding any more detail about which gcc version XC16 is using behind the scenes.

Comment: Ignore that Godbolt link I just edited out of the comment—it had reverted a paste, putting the structure declarations in the same block. Fixing that, it seems like GCC does not warn for structure tags, even in version 10.2 for C with `-Wshadow`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Hmm indeed, since g++ does warn and the documentation mentions some differences between C/C++/ObjC, I am have concluded a bit too quickly. A bug report could make sense.

Comment: regarding: `void main(void) {`  There are only two valid signatures for `main()` (regardless of what some non-compliant compilers might allow)  they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *arg[] )`

Comment: I don't think the return type of main is relevant to my question but I've gone ahead and updated it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C allows new declarations of identifiers in new scopes. When you declare a function or start a compound statement with `{`, that starts a new scope. Iteration and selection statements also start new scopes. Inside a new scope, a new declaration of an identifier generally hides the previous declaration. Since this is legal C, the compiler allows this.

In GCC 4.5.1, [the documentation for `-Wshadow`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) says it warns “whenever a local variable shadows another local variable, parameter or global variable or whenever a built-in function is shadowed.” A structure tag is not a local variable or a built-in function.

Incidentally, the return type of `main` should be `int` except in special situations; using `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv)`, not `void main(void)`.

Comment: On the other hand, warnings are usually for legal but questionable code, and -Wshadow is specifically about this kind of situation, but it is only implemented in the C++ front-end.

Comment: Thank you.  This makes sense.  It is too bad that the Wshadow doesn't catch this as it seems conceptually like what it is designed to warn against.